# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types '{}' and 'number' Ask

Tags: javascript, typescript, sbt, underscore.js

I'm using TypeScript 2.4, sbt, and underscore.
When I use.

```
this.userData.summaryMonth = _.reduce(this.userData.monthValues, (m, n) => m+n, 0);
```

My interface

```
export interface IUserPlan {
    id: number,
    login: string,
    fullName: string,
    role: IUserPlanRole,
    month?: string[]
    monthValues?: number[],
    summaryDay?: 0,
    summaryMonth?: number,
    workingDays?: number,
    nonWorkingDays?: number,
    filterType: string
}
```

I'm getting an error:

```
[info] TypeScript compiling on 1 source(s)
[error] /developer/projects/------/app/assets/admin/statistics/statistics.controller.ts:220: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and '{}'.
[error] this.userData.summaryMonth = _.reduce(this.userData.monthValues, (m, n) => m+n, 0);                                                                                                        
        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (bo/web-assets:typescript) com.typesafe.sbt.web.CompileProblemsException
```

Comment: omg.... It's so easy ... just to assign argument types.. and it helped me

this.userData.summaryMonth = _.reduce(this.userData.monthValues, (m:  number, n: number) => m+n, 0);

Comment: I would asume that `_.reduce` typings seeing `n` as type `{}`. Just tell typescript that `n` is a number (`n : number`)

Comment: exactly. Works very well. thanks!

Comment: Should also be possible to do: `this.userData.summaryMonth = _.reduce<number, number>(this.userData.monthValues, (m, n) => m+n, 0);`